# Entity Framework Core Read & Update Multiple rows - Composite Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, composite-key

I have a table structure like this:

```
ID Code  Value
1  2     text1
2  3     text3
2  4     text4
```

Here ID and Code form the composite primary key i.e. in the above table you cannot have another row with ID = 2 and Code = 4.

Now we are using entity framework core and I have a class called Branch (representing the composite key) and that looks like this:

```
public class Branch
{
 public int ID {get; set;}
 public int Code {get; set;}
}
```

Secondly I have a `List<Branch>` as well. Now I want to do two things:

First make one database call and get the full object (ID, Code, Value) for the entire list of Branch.

After that, I will change the 'Value' for each object.

Then I want to make one database call and save the updated 'Value' for each row.

Currently I am doing this in a loop so it's inefficient.

```
foreach(var x in listOfBranch)
{
  var record = context.Table.Find(x.ID, x.Code);
  record.Value = "new value";
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can we do this in one call? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now I want to do two things:
>
> First make one database call and get the full object (ID, Code, Value) for the entire list of Branch.
>
> After that, I will change the 'Value' for each object.
>
> Then I want to make one database call and save the updated 'Value' for each row.

The second part is easy - just move `SaveChanges()` call outside of the loop.

The first part is tricky. At the time of writing (EF Core 2.0.2), `Contains` can be used only with single property, and joins to in memory collections, `Concat` based queries, or filters like

```
.Where(e => listOfBranch.Any(b => b.ID == e.ID && b.Code == e.Code))
```

all these are not translated to SQL and are evaluated locally.

The only way to get the desired result with a single database query is to build dynamically a filter criteria like this:

```
.Where(e =>
    (e.ID == listOfBranch[0].ID && e.Code == listOfBranch[0].Code)
    ||
    (e.ID == listOfBranch[1].ID && e.Code == listOfBranch[1].Code)
    // ...
    ||
    (e.ID == listOfBranch[N-1].ID && e.Code == listOfBranch[N-1].Code)
)
```

You can build the above predicate using `Expression` class methods as follows (just replace `Record` with the type of entity):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Record));

var body = listOfBranch
    .Select(b => Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "ID"), Expression.Constant(b.ID)),
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Code"), Expression.Constant(b.Code))))
    .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Record, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

and the usage:

```
foreach (var record in context.Table.Where(predicate))
{
    record.Value = "new value";
}
context.SaveChanges();
```